# Create a convenience decorator to generate a Controller from a function using BeanPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I'm looking to write a decorator that takes a very static function and wraps it inside a controller.

Think of it as a global scope utility callable/runnable, so pathvariable/requestbody has to be injected into the parameters. And then it has to automatically be wrapped inside a bean controller with the appropriate getmapping/postmapping to expose it an endpoint

```
@AutoGetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getById(@PathVariable long id) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.getById(id);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

gets transformed to

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
 
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
 
    @GetMapping("users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
 
    @GetMapping("users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getById(@PathVariable long id) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.getById(id);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

(maybe even the service layers).

I'm just looking for a place to start. I think im making a mistake in trying to use BeanPostProcessor and BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor  to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to start doing this ?

Comment: Decorator pattern does not transform code. Decorator pattern adds new behaviour by adding new class

Comment: A little improvement use `Optional` API. `user.map(u -> new ResponseEntity<>(u.get(), HttpStatus.OK)).orElseThrow(RecordNotFoundException::new)`

Comment: @StepUp sure - my thought was where it takes the current function, wraps into a class and generates that class. just a thought..but this is what i want to achieve - where i just define a function and my decorator (or some plugin) transforms it into a bean

Comment: *"that takes a very simple function"* There are no "functions" in Java. Do you mean a method in an existing class?

Comment: You need to use code generation at compile time. It is only one way to achieve such a complex transformation. Examples are [Mapstruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct) or [Lombok](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok).

Comment: How someone will supply the function ? I meant to say where is the function defined.

Comment: @Olivier - my apologies for poor english. i wanted to convey that these are static functions/util functions. im importing a third party library with a large number of functions and trying to generate endpoints for them automatically. so im not able to use the standard way of defining a controller class and annotating methods in it

Comment: @AnishB. the function is defined in global scope. think of it as defined as a utility function. it has no controller, etc around it. on startup, we have to autogenerate the controller classes and wrap these functions so that spring can generate the endpoints

Comment: pardon my english, but ive been thinking of callable/runnables here or anonymous classes here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it could be using the approach described in [Interface Driven Controllers](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-interface-driven-controllers) article with some additions.

As in the article, we can create an interface with the default annotations. Additionally, we can implement the `default` methods and enforce the implementation of the certain methods in the service layer using some generics like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/default")
public interface BasicRestController<ID, T, S extends BasicRestService<T, ID>> {
    @NonNull S getService();

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    default ResponseEntity<T> getById(@PathVariable ID id) {
        return getService().getById(id)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseThrow(RecordNotFoundException::new);
    }

    @GetMapping
    default ResponseEntity<List<T>> getAll() {
        List<T> results = getService().getAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(results);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface BasicRestService<T, ID> {
    Optional<T> getById(ID id);

    List<T> getAll();
}
```

And then use it in the controller like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bars")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BarController implements BasicRestController<Long, Bar, BarService> {
    private final BarService barService;

    @Override
    public @NonNull BarService getService() {
        return barService;
    }
}
```

Minimal working example can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/kasptom/stack-73744318-interface-driven-controller

Comment: @kapstom - thanks for ur attempt. so the question was to create endpoints/beans, etc from static functions. I'm importing a third party library which has a large number of static functions. i want to automatically generate endpoints for them (which means RequestParam is injected into it as well). im not sure about ur solution since u have shown a very standard way of writing endpoints in spring - using a contoller/interface and defining functions in it. can u mention, how to generate endpoints/beans from static functions ?

Comment: @Sandeep If you could provide [the minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and create a new question for it, maybe it will bring more valuable answers. I've missed the information about the 3rd party library and static functions.
To generate the code I would use [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or, easier to use, [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet)